# Instance per JobExecutionContext with Quartz.NET and Autofac

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, autofac, lifecycle, quartz.net

What I'm looking for is having a life-cycle during each execution of a quartz job.  Is there any way to have an `InstancePerJobExecutionContext` life-cycle with Quartz.NET and Autofac?

This is the snippet I'm using already:

```
public class AutofacJobFactory : IJobFactory {
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IJob, ILifetimeScope>
        _childScopesMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<IJob, ILifetimeScope>();

    public AutofacJobFactory(ILifetimeScope container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler) {
        var childScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope();            
        var job = (IJob)childScope.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        _childScopesMap.TryAdd(job, childScope);
        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) {
        if (!_childScopesMap.TryRemove(job, out var scope))
            return;
        try {
            scope.Dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle/log 
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm thinking is there a better/performant/stable way to doing this?

Comment: Scope handling and Quartz can be very annoying, but your solution looks good, it seems to be performant and stable. If you havn't overriden the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` methods in your Jobs then there shouldn't be any problem with this.

Comment: @Rabban Thanks to comment. No I didn't. Actually it seems good to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the used snippet is doing just fine:

```
public class AutofacJobFactory : IJobFactory {
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _container;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<IJob, ILifetimeScope>
        _childScopesMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<IJob, ILifetimeScope>();

    public AutofacJobFactory(ILifetimeScope container) {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler) {
        var childScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope();            
        var job = (IJob)childScope.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        _childScopesMap.TryAdd(job, childScope);
        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job) {
        if (!_childScopesMap.TryRemove(job, out var scope))
            return;
        try {
            scope.Dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle/log 
        }
    }
}
```